# Making servlet serve READONLY text/html resource

Tags: java, servlets

While i am serving text/html resource resource i want to make it the resource as readonly.
And we need to restrict editing the readonly attribute who is downloading the resource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You cannot control that**: when servlet's content is served, it can be stored in a file, a db, etc for later use. This goes beyond servlet (and HTTP) possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You better think about serving a PDF instead.