# Servlet to set read-only permission while File save

Tags: struct, servlets

I want to save a file with read-only options through a servlet.Can someone shed some taughts.

Thanks.

(fyi..I went through this link,so need some other ways through which this can be done.
[Making servlet serve READONLY text/html resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237155/making-servlet-serve-readonly-text-html-resource))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`File.setWritable(false)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setWritable%28boolean%29).

Comment: Hi,I tried doing that but still,I can change the file which I have downloaded.Here is a code snippet which I have used :    File file = new File("1234");
        file.setWritable(false);

        resp.getOutputStream().print(writer.toString());
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" +file + ".xml");       
        resp.setContentType("application/text-xml");

Comment: You're not modifying any file in this snippet. You're not even creating any file on the disk. You're just writing something to the servlet response, and telling the browser that it's a file which has a the name 1234.xml. Could you clarify what you really want to do?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.When a user clicks a button,I want all the data which is on that page to be saved as an XML on the client localMachine.So,We use servlet response to display the open/Save dialog box along with the data.The only reason I used file is for testing,to see if that would impact the actual permissions of the file saved.So,the real need for me is how to make the file which comes out of the servlet response read-Only.Hope I was clear this time.

Comment: Ah. Now I think I understand. You can't do that. The client does what he wants with the stream of bytes that the servlet sends. He can choose to cancel save it as a file, to ignore it, to save it with another name, anything. You won't gain access to the client machine from the server. BTW, the answers to the question you linked to already told it. Do you really think asking it another time would change the reality?

Comment: No,The only reason I asked here again is to check if there is any other work around to handle this case(like design change options etc).I didn't mean to waste anyone times.